# Writing PHP File using PHP Script including variables

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I am writing a PHP File using the following PHP code :
The code to write php file is :

** write.php**

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("writePhp.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "<?php \n error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);\n ";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txtnew = "'$CALENDAR_DISPLAY = 'true';' \n";
fwrite($myfile, $txtnew);
?>
```

The exact output that I want is :

**writePhp.php**

```
<?php    
error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
    $CALENDAR_DISPLAY = 'true';
```

However the **actual result** that I got in my writePhp file is :

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
' = 'true';'
```

When I execute the write.php file, I get a notification :

> **Notice: Undefined variable: CALENDAR_DISPLAY in /var/www/shellPhp/write.php on line 11**

The specific issue that I am facing is that my code is not writing the VARIABLE in the file. Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: `$txtnew = '$CALENDAR_DISPLAY = \'true\';' . "\n";`. PHP replaces the variables inside the double quoted string with values.

Comment: Thanks Bansi! It worked. I appreciate your time and help.